# Converting a list of list of tuples to a DataFrame (First argument: column, Second argument: value)

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, tuples, converters

So I need a DataFrame out of a list_of_list_of_tuples:

My data looks like this:

tuples = [[(5,0.45),(6,0.56)],[(1,0.23),(2,0.54),(6,0.63)],[(3,0.86),(6,0.36)]]

What I need is this:

| index | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 0.45 | 0.56 |
| 2 | 0.23 | 0.54 | nan | nan | nan | 0.63 |
| 3 | nan | nan | 0.86 | nan | nan | 0.36 |

So that the first argument in the tuple is the column, and the second is the value.
An index would be nice also.
Can anyone help me?
I have no idea how to formulate the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert each tuple to dictionary, pass to `DataFrame` constructor and last add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for change order and also add missing columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(x) for x in tuples])

df = df.reindex(range(df.columns.min(), df.columns.max() + 1), axis=1)
print (df)
      1     2     3   4     5     6
0   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN  0.45  0.56
1  0.23  0.54   NaN NaN   NaN  0.63
2   NaN   NaN  0.86 NaN   NaN  0.36
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tuples = [[(5,0.45),(6,0.56)],[(1,0.23),(2,0.54),(6,0.63)],[(3,0.86),(6,0.36)]]

for x in tuples:
    print(x)
    index=[]
    values=[]
    for tuple in x:
        print(tuple[0],tuple[1])
        index.append(tuple[0])
        values.append(tuple[1])
    print(index,values)
```

Comment: are the columns known for the data frame or must they be derived?  I will need to make on pass over the data to get the column names and then a second pass to create the rows using dataframe loc